# keras - how to avoid dimension error when using lambda layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using python with keras over tensorflow and trying to use lambda layers, and keep having the same error, I checked the summary of the model and it all seems ok. The error occures only when training.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist 
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, concatenate,subtract, Lambda
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import SGD

(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = mnist.load_data()
train_x = (train_x / 255.0).reshape(-1, 28*28) 
test_x = (test_x / 255.0).reshape(-1, 28*28)

inp1 = Input(shape=(28*28,))
inp2 = Input(shape=(28*28,))

l1 = Dense(100, activation="relu")
a1 = l1(inp1)
a2 = l1(inp2)
l2 = Dense(100, activation="relu")
b1 = l2(a1)
b2 = l2(a2)
output = Lambda(lambda inputs: inputs[0]-inputs[1], output_shape=(100,))([b1, b2])
model = Model([inp1, inp2], [output])
model.compile(loss=binary_crossentropy, optimizer=SGD())

y = train_y[:1]
model.fit([train_x[:1], train_x[:1]], y)
```

I get this error

> Error when checking target: expected lambda_13 to have shape (100,)
>   but got array with shape (1,)

When using `model.predict` on the same data, it predicts without any error. What is the issue here? Thanks

Comment: Problem is you are expecting model to predict in the shape of `(100,)` and you are trying to fit with data which has shape of (1,). Here, `output_shape=(100,)`  should be `1` if you want to use current `y`.

Comment: great, thanks, care to post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are expecting model to predict in the shape of (100,) and you are trying to fit with data which has shape of (1,). Here, output_shape=(100,) should be 1 if you want to use current y.

And one more thing if you want to do classification of numbers with output with shape of `(1,)`. You also need to change `model.compile(loss=binary_crossentropy, optimizer=SGD())` to `model.compile(loss=sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=SGD())`.  For more information about `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, you can check for [keras documentation](https://keras.io/losses/). And you can find [here](https://jovianlin.io/cat-crossentropy-vs-sparse-cat-crossentropy/) the difference between `categorical_crossentropy` and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.